# An AVCaptureOutput instance may not be added to more than one session error Swift

Tags: ios, swift, avcapturesession

I am trying to record video in my iPhone app using `AVCaptureSession`. It works fine for the first time, however if I click Record button for the second time the App terminates with the error below:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[AVCaptureSession
>   addOutput:] An AVCaptureOutput instance may not be added to more than
>   one session'

First I was getting cannot support multiple `video / audio` sessions error and I have added the code to check if the input is added before adding another input. Now I'm getting this new error.

Any help is appreciated.

```
class CaptureViewViewController: BaseViewController,AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate{

let session: AVCaptureSession = AVCaptureSession()
var movieOutput = AVCaptureMovieFileOutput()

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    session.beginConfiguration()
    session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSession.Preset.high

    if let device = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInWideAngleCamera, for: AVMediaType.video, position: .front)
        {
            if let audioDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: AVMediaType.audio){

                do {
                    let audioInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: audioDevice)
                    if let inputs = session.inputs as? [AVCaptureDeviceInput] {
                        for input in inputs {
                            session.removeInput(input)
                        }
                    }
                    self.session.addInput(audioInput)
                } catch {
                    print("Unable to add audio device to the recording.")
                }
             }
             do {
                if let inputs = session.inputs as? [AVCaptureDeviceInput] {
                    for input in inputs {
                        session.removeInput(input)
                    }
                }
                try session.addInput(AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: device))

            } catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }

            let previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: session)
            self.preViewImage.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)
            previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
            previewLayer.frame = self.preViewImage.layer.bounds
        }
            movieOutput.movieFragmentInterval = CMTime.invalid
            session.addOutput(movieOutput
            session.commitConfiguration()
            session.startRunning()

}

@IBAction func handleMoviewRecord(_ sender: Any) {

        if videoRecordState == .stop {

//            let documentsUrl = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first! as NSURL
//            if let fileUrl = documentsUrl.appendingPathComponent( "output.mov" )?.absoluteURL {
//                print(fileUrl)
            let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
            let fileUrl = paths[0].appendingPathComponent("output.mov")
            try? FileManager.default.removeItem(at: fileUrl)
            movieOutput.startRecording(to: fileUrl, recordingDelegate: self)

           // (to: URL(fileURLWithPath: paths), recordingDelegate: self)
           recordVideoButton.setTitle("Stop Recording", for: .normal)
           recordVideoButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
           videoRecordState = .start
          // }
        }else {
           self.movieOutput.stopRecording()
            session.stopRunning()
           recordVideoButton.setTitle("Start Recording", for: .normal)
           videoRecordState = .stop
           session.removeOutput(movieOutput)

        }
    }

     func fileOutput(_ output: AVCaptureFileOutput, didFinishRecordingTo outputFileURL: URL, from connections: [AVCaptureConnection], error: Error?) {
                print("FINISHED \(Error.self)")

                  if error == nil {
                      UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(outputFileURL.path, nil, nil, nil)
                        UserDefaults.set(.videoPath, to: outputFileURL.path)
                    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "refresh"), object: nil)
                    navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)

           }
        }
```

Comment: You don't seem to call `stopRunning` nor `removeOutput` on your session.

Comment: I'm calling stopRecording but not stopRunning, where do I need to call that method?

Comment: Probably at the same place; you need to completely clean up your capture

Comment: I think the problem is that you need to create a new output instance each time you record. You can't allocate `movieOutput` once and keep using it

Comment: Your code doesn't show where you allocate `movieOutput`

Comment: I've created a variable of type AVCaptureMovieFileOutput at the top, I've updated the code above. Please check. Thank you.

Comment: So you need to assign a new instance of `AVCaptureOutput` to that property each time you want to record

Comment: Sorry I couldn't reply earlier but here is the root cause of the issue: I was calling the DispatchQueue.main twice for the same function which created two AVCaptureOutput instances in one session. Altered the function with one DispatchQueue.main call and the issue is resolved. I don't have to call the  stopRunning nor removeOutput anymore. Thanks for looking into it.